# BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL flag on result C++

Tags: c++, boost-test

I would like to get a flag result of test for to do something like this:

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(...);

if (flag == sucess){
   then this
}
else
{
   this
}
```

any idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/reference/BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL.html)

> BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( left, right )
>
> The same as BOOST_CHECK( left == right ).

So, you can just use

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(a, b);
const bool flag = (a == b);
```

I think, there is no other way.

Comment: hum, so boost does not offer so tools for that's
:(

Comment: @GaetanGriffonDuBellay no, it checks equality internally, probably there is no way to get check result from boost.

Comment: GaetanGriffon: if I understand correctly, if the test in BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL fails then it will throw an exception, so the premise of the question doesn't make much sense (unless you catch that exception, but it would be quite ugly)

Comment: @ChrisBeck no, it will not throw exception. It's `CHECK`, only message will be printed.